# Why this piece of code isn't compilable

Tags: java, generics

Here the small piece of code and I don't understand why the javac can't compile it. What I miss? Is there are any errors?

```
public class HelloWorld<T> {
    private static enum Type {
    }

    private T value;
    private List<Type> types = new ArrayList<>();

    public T getValue() { return value; }

    public List<Type> getTypes() { return types; }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for ( Type type : new HelloWorld().getTypes() ) { // Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to HelloWorld.Type

        }
    }
}
```

Why is `getTypes()` returning an `Object` (raw) list when it is should `Type` list?

[Link to online compiler](http://goo.gl/eAjoXM)

Comment: ... you linked to the online compiler, but did not read its output? `HelloWorld.java:17: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Type` is the error it gives.

Comment: I saw the error. Why it's happening? The getTypes() isn't use generic type parameter. The return type of the method is set explicitly.

Comment: The fact that "Type" is private and "getTypes" publicly return a list of those private objects, it bugs nobody but me ?

Comment: You have declared generic class `HelloWorld` and initialized it without parameter: `new HelloWorld<TYPE_NEEDED>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a compiler limitation to me. `getTypes` always returns a `List<Type>`, so using the raw `HelloWorld` type should make no difference.

That said, either of these two solutions will overcome the error :

1. Create a parameterized type of `HelloWorld` instead of a raw type :

   ```
   for (Type type : new HelloWorld<Integer>().getTypes() ) { // any type will do, I chose 
                                                             // Integer arbitrarily to show
                                                             // that it doesn't matter

   }
   ```
2. Use a local variable to store the List before using it :

   ```
   List<Type> types = new HelloWorld().getTypes();
   for (Type type : types) { 

   }
   ```

Anyway, parameterized types should always be preferred over raw types, so I'll use the first solution (with whatever type parameter makes sense in your class).

Comment: Or even without any parameter is working fine, like `new HelloWorld<>().getTypes();`

Comment: @Codebender I didn't test that, since it requires Java 7 or higher. `new HelloWorld<Object>().getTypes()` also works, which is funny.

Comment: @Eran yours suggestions is working! But I'd like to understand is it a workaround or the typical use of classes with generics? It's about first case. Because for me it's not clear why the field(types) declared without generic information somehow depends on the generic declaration while class instantiation. Looks like the <> makes more magic that I though before.

Comment: @Mirian I don't know why the original code doesn't work. It somehow confuses the compiler. However, since you are always advised to use parameterized types instead of raw types, it's not a real issue. I would call my first suggestion a workaround if there was any real need to ever use it, but since parameterized types are a better solution, there's no need for it.

Comment: @Eran looks like the compiler "erase" or "miss" information about generic at getTypes() return type and <> helps it to remember.

Comment: *This looks like a compiler limitation to me.* I found **initialising a raw type object and calling a method that returns a variable having generics, this variable will also be converted to RAW TYPE**.

Comment: @Blip good finding - this is exactly the strength of the compiler not a limitation. I have read about it in Java8 documentation an it is detailed specified as such.

Comment: @MaxZoom Why have you read about it in Java8? Can you please find a link to this documentation?

Comment: I have read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6) . Method `getTypes(..)` is not a generic method, so the third part applies

Answer (score 1):

While experimenting with your code I noticed something very interesting. In order to remove the compiler error:

> Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to
>   HelloWorld.Type

Since it is stating the returned element is of type `Object` I decided to type cast it to `List<Type>` as shown:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    for ( Type type : (List<Type>)new HelloWorld().getTypes() ) { 

    }
}
```

This compiled successfully with warning so I used the `-Xlint` with `javac` to see what is the warning and I found the following:

```
HelloWorld.java:15: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HelloWorld
        for ( Type type : (List<Type>)new HelloWorld().getTypes() ) {
                                          ^
  missing type arguments for generic class HelloWorld<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:15: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        for ( Type type : (List<Type>)new HelloWorld().getTypes() ) {
                                                               ^
  required: List<Type>
  found:    List
2 warnings
```

Here I was astonished to see the second warning. It states that required is `List<Type>` but found `List` a **RAW TYPE**. So it means that if you initialise a raw type object and call a method that returns a variable having generics, this variable will also be converted to **RAW TYPE**. In order to test this I implemented a class `HelloWorldTest` as :

```
public class HelloWorldTest<T>{
    private T t;

    public HelloWorldTest(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T getT(){
        return t;
    }
}
```

Then I changed your code to test the condition as :

```
public class HelloWorld<T> {

    private HelloWorldTest<Integer> test = new HelloWorldTest<>(1);

    public HelloWorldTest<Integer> getTest(){
        return test;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        HelloWorldTest<Integer> hello = new HelloWorld().getTest();
    }
}
```

This compiles successfully but with warnings so using `-Xlint` switch to compile I get the following Warnings:

```
HelloWorld.java:10: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HelloWorld
        HelloWorldTest<Integer> hello = new HelloWorld().getTest();
                                            ^
  missing type arguments for generic class HelloWorld<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:10: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        HelloWorldTest<Integer> hello = new HelloWorld().getTest();
                                                                ^
  required: HelloWorldTest<Integer>
  found:    HelloWorldTest
2 warnings
```

So, Here also we find that the `HelloWorldTest` has been converted to a raw type.

Finally we can infer that : **If you initialise a raw type object and call a method that returns a variable having generics, this variable will also be converted to RAW TYPE**.

Now when I replaced

```
    HelloWorldTest<Integer> hello = new HelloWorld().getTest();
```

with

```
    Integer hello = new HelloWorld().getTest().getT();
```

As expected I got the error :

```
HelloWorld.java:10: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
        Integer hello = new HelloWorld().getTest().getT();
                                                       ^
1 error
```

Finally if you replace the main method in my implementation of `HelloWorld` class with:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String hello = (String) new HelloWorld().getTest().getT();
    }
```

It compiles successfully with only warning being:

```
HelloWorld.java:10: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HelloWorld
            String hello = (String) new HelloWorld().getTest().getT();
                                        ^
  missing type arguments for generic class HelloWorld<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class HelloWorld
1 warning
```

This is quite misleading as this will definitely run into runtime errors and again illustrates the dangers of **RAW TYPE** in generics.

Answer (score 0):

change `for` loop to add a generic type for the class:

for e.g: I have just used '`Type`' as an example here.

```
for ( Type type : new HelloWorld<Type>().getTypes() ) {
```

Edit :

It could be 'String' as well as pointed out in the comments.(thanks for that).
In your case, it should be actual type which you need for that class.

The idea is that the generic type was missing which needs to be added.

Comment: While this answer maybe correct, you should also explain why the error and why your answer will fix it. That will help the OP more.

Comment: The generic type parameter T is not used anywhere in the `getTypes` method, so why should it matter? `getTypes` should return a `List<Type>` regardless of the generic type parameter (`new HelloWorld<String>().getTypes()` should still return a `List<Type>`).

Comment: I would suggest `new HelloWorld<?>` instead of `new HelloWorld<Type>`

Comment: `and hence getTypes() method would return an object of type Object` - why? `public List<Type> getTypes() { return types; }` - always returns `List<Type>`. Why would it ever return `Object`?

Comment: This is fun! I tried it in my IDE and when I instantiate `new HelloWorld()` (a raw type), the _whole_ type is raw. Therefore, `getTypes()` suddenly returns a raw `List`. An interesting behaviour and one more reason to never ever use raw types!

Comment: In the answer by **Eran**, it is shown how this code works even using **RAW TYPE**

Answer (score 0):

Within `main` method:

```
for ( Type type : new HelloWorld().getTypes() ) {//Here also you did not mention the type for the new object since 
}
```

Try this in main method:

```
for ( Type type : new HelloWorld<Type>().getTypes() ) {

}
```

Comment: When you have declared `List<Type>` then there is no need to add `Type` to `ArrayList` initialisation.

Comment: Yeah sure. But in the code he have put like `new ArrayList<>()`. This should be either `new ArrayList()` or `new ArrayList<Type>()`. Isn't it? Otherwise there will be an error in the line `Multiple markers at this line
 - '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
 - ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized
 - Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to `

Comment: _"//here you don't need to mention even the type at all: `new ArrayList();`"_ ... still not correct. In Java 7, `new ArrayList<>()` is perfectly fine and is actually the recommended way to instantiate generic types. Look up "Java 7 diamond operator".

Comment: @Slanec That's true. I'll correct my answer. But I was checking in 6. So I got the above error as I mentioned in the above comment.